# D3 Nest - Sorting Values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to sort a dataset by key and value using D3.nest(), both according to a custom defined array order. The key sorting is working without issue, but the but I'm not able to get the values sorted.

My custom sort arrays are defined as:

```
var priority_source_order = ["Biological","Water","Sediment","Eco-Fish"];
var priority_indicator_order = ["Biological Status","Water Quality Index","Phosphorus","Nitrogen","Dissolved Oxygen","Water Clarity","Chlorophyll a","Sediment Quality Index","Sediment Contaminants","Sediment Toxicity","Fish Quality Index"];
```

The .sortKeys method works fine, but I'm not able to sort the values. This is likely because there are multiple key/value pairs nested inside of the "values" key that D3.nest() creates and the function doesn't know which key needs to be sorted. Here is my code:

```
var final_data = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { 
                return d[ncca_ce_source];
            })
            .sortKeys(function(a,b) { 
                return priority_source_order.indexOf(a) - priority_source_order.indexOf(b); 
            })
            .sortValues(function(a,b) { 
                return priority_indicator_order.indexOf(a) - priority_indicator_order.indexOf(b); 
            })
            .entries(cond_est_data);
```

My data currently looks like:

```
[
 {
  "key": "Biological",
  "values": [
   {
    "Type": "National",
    "Indicator.Plain.Language": "Benthic Index"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "key": "Water",
  "values": [
   {
    "Type": "National",
    "Indicator.Plain.Language": "Chlorophyll a"
   },
   {
    "Type": "National",
    "Indicator.Plain.Language": "Dissolved Oxygen"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to sort on the "Indicator.Plain.Language" key according to the order of the priority_indicator_order array? As you can see by the output above, the "key" for Biological and Water are sorted properly. However, the values for "Indicator.Plain.Language" are not in the order defined by the priority_indicator_order array.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to revisit the ternary
`return (priority_indicator_order.indexOf(a) - priority_indicator_order.indexOf(b) ? 1 : -1);` I'm pretty sure this will always return the first expression (1).

Comment: I think I need to clarify my question a bit. Going to update now.

Comment: Got it, had to modify the sortValue to:  return priority_indicator_order.indexOf(a[ncca_ce_indic_plain]) - priority_indicator_order.indexOf(b[ncca_ce_indic_plain]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by modifying the .sortValues method to the following:

```
.sortValues(function(a,b) { 
    return priority_indicator_order.indexOf(a[ncca_ce_indic_plain]) - priority_indicator_order.indexOf(b[ncca_ce_indic_plain]); 
})
```